# How to acquire a user's GPS location on an Android (2.2) device

Tags: java, android, gps, android-location

I am attempting to simply acquire the user's GPS location, but my application crashes when trying to get the latitude and longitude of the device.  See code for where the error occurs..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    final double longitude = location.getLongitude();  //error occurs here
    final double latitude = location.getLatitude();    //and here

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            //longitude = location.getLongitude();
            //latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };
    //update location via GPS PROVIDER
    //can also use LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}
```

I am also including the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

so I'm not quite sure why this does not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you get a crash, it means you get a callstack. You may want to post it.

Comment: Sounds like location = null, but like Mike said...we need the log.

Comment: @EboMike @user432209 Sorry about that. I am getting a NULLPointerException.  location = null.  So I'm assuming that when it tries to get the user's last known location, a location is not found.  Is there a better/different way to find a user's location instead of using getLastKnownLocation?

Comment: You need to show the full callstack. It contains the exact line on which the problem occurs, and potentially further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check this StackOverflow Question: [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most probably at: lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

It is because the getLastKnownLocation is a non blocking call and assuming the application has just started there is no 'last known location' that the system has. You might want to loop till you dont get a non-null value for getLastKnownLocation.